# Silverlight: Transition effects in SL4? Another framework?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, effects, transition

i am looking for some transition effects in SL4. Do these come standard or is there some kind of framework addon?

Does anyone know of examples, tutorials.

If a framework exists is there documentation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SL4 framework has very powerful animation and storyboard features, but no transitions concepts built in. However the Silverlight Toolkit, which is developed by Microsoft, has a TransitioningContentControl:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

This will provide nice transitions as you change the content which it contains. See the following tutorial:

http://jesseliberty.com/2009/04/29/animated-visual-state-transitions-with-the-transitioning-content-control/

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight.FX has a good set of transitions.
I found it easy to use.

http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Effects-Transitions.aspx